# Display .Net assembly properties including public key in windows explorer

Tags: .net

Is there an easy way to get properties of a .NET assembly including its public key token and culture info using windows explorer on my windows 7 PC.

Currently I use Reflector to get this info, but surely there should be an easier way that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I made a tool for just that purpose, you can get it at http://asgaard.homelinux.org/AssemblyInfo/ , the code is at http://asgaard.homelinux.org/svn/csharp/AssemblyInfo/ . There's nothing smart about the tool - you might need to compile it for .NET 4.0 if you want to check .NET 4.0 assemblies, or change it to x64 to check x64 assemblies though.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi nos, for some reason the links seem broken!

Comment: links appear to be broken again.